# Error creating bean with name 'jmsConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I want to use a Springboot Apache Camel application to get a message on IBM MQ. I am currently setting up the JMS connection, but I receive an error about a bean. Not sure what is going on because I thought that de bean is being defined now.

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.CommonConstants;
//import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;


@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class JmsConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsComponent.class);
    private String host = "xxx";
    private int port = 4510;
    private String queueManager = "xxx";
    private String channel = "xxx";
    //private String username = "";
    //private String password = "";
    private String sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";

    @Value("${keyStore}")
    private String keyStore;

    @Value("${keyStorePassword}")
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @Value("${trustStore}")
    private String trustStore;

    @Value("${trustStorepassword}")
    private String trustStorePassword;


    @Bean
    public JmsComponent mq() {
        JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        return jmsComponent;
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        try {
            //Load trust store
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);
            //Load keystore
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);

            //keystore fetch
            String keystoreKey = "${keyStorePassword}";
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("${keyStore}"),
                    keystoreKey.toCharArray());

            // Create key manager
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keystoreKey.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

            // Create trust manager
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            // Initialize SSLContext
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
            sslContext.init(km, tm, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);

            MQEnvironment.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.8.jar!/:3.0.8]
at nl.rabobank.mqputter.MqPutterApplication.main(MqPutterApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'keyStore' in value "${keyStore}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:920) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:711) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:694) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
... 24 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite obvious:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'keyStore' in value "${keyStore}"

It means that you have not set that property anywhere.

Note that you can add a default value for a missing property `"${keyStore:someDefault}"`